# encode url using silverstripe - urlencode

Tags: silverstripe

### Magazine.ss

```
  <% with $Magazine %>
    <h1>$Title</h1>
    <iframe src="http://docs.google.com/viewer?url={$Document.AbsoluteURL}&embedded=true" width="100%" height="842"></iframe>
  <% end_with %>
```

if you check the above code, it print url as  'http://masapulari.com/assets/Uploads/dummy.pdf .
Magazine is a DataObject class and Document is File Type, as you see below.
Is there a way to print urlencode of $Document.AbsoluteURL?

class Magazine extends DataObject {

```
private static $db = array(
  'Title'=>'VarChar',
  'Date' => 'Date',
);

private static $has_one = array(
  'Photo' => 'Image',
  'Document' => 'File'
);
```

}

class Magazine_Controller extends Page_Controller {

```
private static $allowed_actions = array (
    'index','view'
      );

public function init() {
    parent::init();

    // Note: you should use SS template require tags inside your templates 
    // instead of putting Requirements calls here.  However these are 
    // included so that our older themes still work
    Requirements::themedCSS('reset');
    Requirements::themedCSS('layout'); 
    Requirements::themedCSS('typography'); 
    Requirements::themedCSS('form'); 
}   

public function view(){
  $params = $this->getURLParams();
  $id = (int)$params['ID'];

  $data = $this->Magazine($id);   

    return $this->customise(array(
        'Magazine'=>$data
    ))->renderWith(array( 'Magazine', 'Page'));       
}

public function Magazine($id){
  $data = DataObject::get_by_id('Magazine',$id);            
    return $data;      
}
```

}

Comment: class Magazine extends DataObject {

 private static $db = array(
   'Title'=>'VarChar',
   'Date' => 'Date',
 );

 private static $has_one = array(
   'Photo' => 'Image',
   'Document' => 'File'
 );
 
      public function getEncodedURL() {
   if ($this->Document() && $this->Document()->exists()) {
       return urlencode($this->Document()->getAbsoluteURL());
   }
      }

      public function getTitle(){
 return $this->getField('Title');
      }

      /*
     public function PrintURL() {
  return '\\' ;
     }
     */

}

Answer (score 4):

You can use `$Document.AbsoluteURL.URLATT` to urlencode a field.

Answer (score 1):

in SilverStripe you can always create new methods on a DataObject or Controller. Those methods will automatically become available in the template.

```
class Magazine extends DataObject {
    private static $db = array(
        'Title' => 'VarChar',
        'Date' => 'Date',
    );
    private static $has_one = array(
        'Photo' => 'Image',
        'Document' => 'File',
    );
    public function EncodedDocumentURL() {
        if ($this->Document() && $this->Document()->exists()) {
            return urlencode($this->Document()->getAbsoluteURL());
        }
    }
}
```

in template you can use:

```
<% with $Magazine %>
    <h1>$Title</h1>
    <iframe src="http://docs.google.com/viewer?url={$EncodedDocumentURL}&embedded=true" width="100%" height="842"></iframe>
<% end_with %>
```

Comment: I have updated the Magazine as above, unfortunately $Document.EncodedURL did not call EncodedURL() function

Comment: ah, my mistake, it's just $EncodedURL(), because its a method on the Magazine and not on the Document. I will edit the answer and rename it to `$EncodedDocumentURL`.

Comment: if you now have a working solution, please accept either one of the answers, to mark this question as resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I solved by adding get function 'getEncodedURL'

class Magazine extends DataObject {

```
private static $db = array(
  'Title'=>'VarChar',
  'Date' => 'Date',
);

private static $has_one = array(
  'Photo' => 'Image',
  'Document' => 'File'
);

  public function getEncodedURL() {
  //return '\\' ;
  if ($this->Document() && $this->Document()->exists()) {
      return urlencode($this->Document()->getAbsoluteURL());
  }
  }

  public function getTitle(){
return $this->getField('Title');
  }

  /*
 public function PrintURL() {
 return '\\' ;
 }
 */
```

}

in the template

```
  <% with $Magazine %>
    <h1>$Title</h1>                 
    <iframe src="http://docs.google.com/viewer?url={$EncodedURL}&embedded=true" width="100%" height="842"></iframe>
  <% end_with %>
```

Thanks Zauberfisch for pointing me in right direction